# Javascript get last multiple of screen width by 600

Tags: javascript, math

I've got a client that is insistent on using two images as their background image, where the first one tile's the width of the screen then the second one has a fade out at far right. The client is insistent on using that fade out on the farthest right side to finish off so it doesn't look weird.

His tile background image is 600px wide, this is a zebra pattern! So it has to line up.

So to get the last image to line up right with the pattern I have to somehow using JS tell it to place that last Div at the farthest most multiple of 600px from the right of the screen. I've got the div positioning from the right, what I cannot get in JS is to calculate what pixel from the left is the farthest most multiple of 600.

I'm racking my brain here and can't figure that one out, how to calculate from a large number what the last multiple of 600 is.

Any ideas?

So if a screen is 1235 wide from left side to scrollbar then the farthest most multiple of 600 is 600 :)

But if a screen is 2564 wide then the farthest multiple of 600 would be 1800.

Comment: Looks to me that a possible formular to get those values is `(Math.floor(x / 600) - 1) * 600`

Comment: @Qnan: If the function should return `600` for `1235` and not `1200` (same for the other value), then you have to multiple by one less than the number of times `600` fits into the number. `1235 = 2 * 600 + 35 => 1 * 600 = 600` and `2564 = 4 * 600 + 164 => 3 * 600 = 1800`.

Comment: ah, I see... but doesn't that mean that there will be a gap of 35px on the right? I guess that's a question for @jfreak53

Comment: Gaps fine, I fill with white after :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First divide by the number you want a multiple of, then `floor` or `ceil` depending on your needs, then multiply by the number again. This will give you the nearest multiple below (respectively above) of the given number.

However, I personally did something not so different from this. I had a parallax scrolling background effect, and on the sides of the screen I had a gradient from transparent to a solid colour to fade the background out before it hit the edge of the screen. This was done simply by adding a background image with the gradient at the side of the screen, no calculation needed.

Comment: it's Math.floor() in this case

Comment: Great, that was really bugging me the math of it all! ha ha  I tried the other option of just background image, but since it's a zebra pattern without the calculation the patterns don't line up from the repeat background image and the end image.

Comment: @jfreak53 make sure that works when the screen width is a multiple of 600, like 1200. I think you'll need a special case for that

Comment: I think you might need `Math.ceil(...)-1` rather than `Math.floor()` to handle that "multiple of 600" case.